# Jquery function works for Chrome but not Firefox and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Currently I am working on an resize function , it works perfectly on chrome but not either ff or safari. (The book position is move to right and bottom than normal) Are there any function not support in those browser? Please have a look , thanks.

**Functions call when Resize :**

```
$(window).resize(function() {

if (!isiPhone()) {
    Book.book_position();
    Book.zoom_auto();
    //Book.dragdrop_init();
}
    //calculate_zoom_factor();

});
```

**book_position()**

```
book_position: function() {
    book_height = $('#page').height();
    book_width  = $('#page').width();

    half_height = (book_height/2)+30;
    half_width  = book_width/2;
    $('#page').css({ left: '50%', top: '50%', margin: '-'+half_height+'px auto 0 -'+half_width+'px' });
},
```

**zoom_auto()**

```
zoom_auto: function() {

    dbl_clicked = false;
    current_zoom_step = 0;
    //calculate_zoom_factor(true);

    screen_height   = $(window).height();
    book_width      = $('#book').width();

    screen_width    = $(window).width()-100;
    book_height     = $('#book').height();

    if (isiPhone()) {

        var new_height      = screen_height - 100;
        var ratio           = new_height / book_height;         
        var new_width       = book_width * ratio;

        $('#page').css({ width: new_width, height: new_height });
        $('#book').turn('size', new_width, new_height);

    } else {

        Book.scaleStart();

        current_window_width = $(window).width();
        current_window_height = $(window).height();

        if (current_window_width != window_width) {
            if( $('#page').height() < ($(window).height() - 96) ) {
                Book.scaleVertical();
            }
            if( $('#page').width() > ($(window).width() - 100) ) {
                Book.scaleHorizontal();
            } 
        }

        if (current_window_height != window_height) {
            if( $('#page').width() < ($(window).width() - 100) ) {
                Book.scaleVertical();
            }

            if( $('#page').height() > ($(window).height() - 96) ) {
                Book.scaleVertical();
            }
        }

        deltaW= $('#page').width()-current_window_width;
        deltaH= $('#page').height()-current_window_height;

        if(deltaW>deltaH){
            Book.scaleHorizontal();
        }else{
            Book.scaleVertical();
        }


        if (( $(window).width() > default_book_width ) && ( $(window).height() > (default_book_height+100) )) {

            $('#page').css({ width: default_page_width, height: default_page_height });
            $('#book').turn('size',default_book_width,default_book_height);
        }

    }
},
```

**scaleVertical (called in zoom_auto)**

```
scaleVertical: function() {
    new_height      = $(window).height() - 116;
    ratio           = new_height / $('#page').height();         
    new_width       = $('#page').width() * ratio;
    $('#page').css({ width: new_width, height: new_height });
    $('#book').turn('size', new_width, new_height);
},
```

**scaleHoriztional (called in zoom_auto)**

```
scaleHorizontal: function() {
    new_width   = $(window).width()-100;
    ratio       = new_width / $('#page').width();
    new_height  = $('#page').height() * ratio;
    $('#page').css({ width: new_width, height: new_height });
    $('#book').turn('size', new_width, new_height);
},
```

Comment: I'd suggest you track down the root of the problem by debugging your code step by step and once you find it come back with that particular piece of code, explain the expected output and create a jsFiddle demo. That way more people will be able/willing to help.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, of course I am not expecting any solution or fixed code, I would appreciate any code skimming and find any statement is not compatible with ff/ safari , thanks

Comment: There is no way to "find any statement that is not compatible". Did you do what @elclanrs said, and stepped through the code using a debugger and/or created a jsFiddle for people to try out?